# Getting data from AJAX in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I follow the website and successfully get the AJAX data from jobs page for Apple.com

The teaching website: http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/

here is the complete code, which is correct:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class AppleJobsScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.search_request = {
            "jobType":"0",
            "sortBy":"req_open_dt",
            "sortOrder":"1",
            "filters":{
                "locations":{
                    "location":[{
                        "type":"0",
                        "code":"USA"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "pageNumber":"0"
        }
    def scrape(self):
        jobs = self.scrape_jobs()
        for job in jobs:
            #print(job)
            pass
    def scrape_jobs(self, max_pages=3):
        jobs = []
        pageno = 0
        self.search_request['pageNumber'] = pageno

        while pageno < max_pages:
            payload = {
                'searchRequestJson': json.dumps(self.search_request),
                'clientOffset': '-300'
            }

            r = requests.post(
                url='https://jobs.apple.com/us/search/search-result',
                data=payload,
                headers={
                     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            )

            s = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
            if not s.requisition:
                break

            for r in s.findAll('requisition'):
                job = {}
                job['jobid'] = r.jobid.text
                job['title'] = r.postingtitle and \
                    r.postingtitle.text or r.retailpostingtitle.text
                job['location'] = r.location.text
                jobs.append(job)

             # Next page
            pageno += 1
            self.search_request['pageNumber'] = pageno

        return jobs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = AppleJobsScraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

I almost understand the code provided by the website, except one of a little piece of section.

```
for r in s.findAll('requisition'):
    job = {}
    job['jobid'] = r.jobid.text
    job['title'] = r.postingtitle and \
        r.postingtitle.text or r.retailpostingtitle.text
    job['location'] = r.location.text
    jobs.append(job)
```

I am curious about what `s.findAll('requisition')` means.

Of course, I should print out the website text by `print(s.get_text())` to see what the source code of website looks like.

But what I get does not look like a website code, which makes me more confused.

So I want to know why the code can use `s.findAll('requisition')` to get the data.

And why the code know it can use `job['jobid']`, `job['title']`, `job['location']` to get the data it wants.

I am really appreciate for your help!

Comment: check documentation for BeautifulSoup - this is html parser, so it is parsing html and spliting it into internal structure that can be traversized by multiple parameters, this specific one is using xml tag names

Comment: @Jerzyk So `requisition` is one of the tags in XML? And how does the programmer know he can use `job['jobid']`, `job['title']`, `job['location']` to get the data he wants? I find no clue to know it.

Comment: You are extracting data from known source, so you should know, if not - analyze data returned by service and then pares it with dedicated tools ([BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in this example)

Comment: I agree with you. But can you tell me how to know the keyword, `jobid`, `title` and `location`, in this case?

Comment: requisition is a tag name. This code finds all the <requisition> Tags in the document:

Comment: this is question to you, *you* are calling webservice, so you should know what data do you expect in return, everything else is how to parse data end extract parts of what you get from the webservice

Answer (score 0):

In that code you are using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which is a HTML parser. This tool provides to you the `findAll` method, which will find all the "requisition" tags on the document. So, this methods return a list containing all the matches, and each list element is a `Tag object`, and as you can read on the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag), a `Tag object` is a tag in the original document.